# Prevent Webpack SplitChunksPlugin from generating CSS files

Tags: javascript, webpack, mini-css-extract-plugin, webpack-splitchunks

I use SplitChunksPlugin to move all vendor JS from `vendor/` and `node_modules/` folders into a separate file:

```
splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/](vendor|node_modules)[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
    }
},
```

I also use MiniCssExtractPlugin to compile and move my SCSS styles into a separate folder.

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: './assets/css/[name].bundle.css',
}),
```

They two together also create a `vendor.bundle.css` I *don't need* at all because all of my styles are generated from SCSS files. Any way to prevent it from being generated?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all I needed was do a test properly:

```
test: /[\\/](vendor|node_modules)[\\/](?=.*\.js$)/,
```

So it only looked up JavaScript files.